# Force window.scroll() on the main div after display

Tags: jquery

While my blog is being loaded I display a loading gif. After the page is 100% loaded I toggle hide/show between the `#loading div`, which contains the gif, and `#main div`, which contains the whole website.

Before I did not have the loading gif and `$(window).scroll()` was working like a charm, but after adding it, `$(window).scroll()` stopped working.

I am assuming that `$(window).scroll()` does not work on a div that has `display: none;` as a style property because there is nothing to scroll. I tried adding it to `$(window).ready()` == Fail;

Is there a possible way to force this function on `#main` right after it's displayed?

Thank you!

```css
html { scroll-behavior: smooth; }
```

```js
function hideLoader() {
   $('#loading>img').hide();
   $('#main').show();
};

$(window).ready(hideLoader);

setTimeout(hideLoader, 20 * 1000);

$(window).scroll({
  top: 150, 
  left: 0, 
  behavior: 'smooth',
});
```

Comment: for main div may be you can try with z-index : -1 then after load make it +1 so you dont have to show hide main div and scroll will also get width and height

Comment: @BinitGhetiya no luck :/

Comment: can't you put window.scroll after window load ? did you tried that ?

Comment: @BinitGhetiya what i have tried: i have put `$(window).scroll()` inside `$(window).ready()`,  and it didn't get triggered...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your currently instructing the page to scroll immediately, whilst the loading GIF is displayed and before the page content is made visible.

I'd imagine you need the content showing in order to give the page enough height to make it scrollable.

You can put `window.scroll()` at the bottom of `hideLoader()` so that your content is showing before trying to scroll the page.

```
function hideLoader() {
  // 1. Hide the loading GIF.
  $('#loading>img').hide();

  // 2. Show the page content.
  $('#main').show();

  // 3. Scroll down the page now that the content is visible.
  window.scroll({
    top: 150, 
    left: 0, 
    behavior: 'smooth',
 });
};
```

**Edit:**

`$(window).scroll()` => `window.scroll()`

Comment: i fixed it by changing `$(window).scroll` => `window.scroll` ... change your answer so i can accept it.